# React Native Image uri different behaviour on Android and IOS?

Tags: javascript, react-native

weird thing happening on React Native Image component. 
This uri would load on IOS but not Android for an Image component:

```
  <Image
    source={{uri: 'http://i.imgur.com/vKRaKDX.png'}}
    style={{height: 300}}
   />
```

whilst this one

```
  <Image
      source={{uri: 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/WXWOptDbw8QrmJ6HhsQVoRpDvqXIFbrgkOtI71d2lKkkDQhQMweVha4VD1rDEFsmphVKogC26oYn39FBXeyiLROJSHdUdP0JzF2Dx8wc125wh886iyU'}}
       style={{height: 300}}
    />
```

Would load on Android and not IOS. The only difference i can see is the .PNG at the end, that makes it work on IOS but not Android and viceversa.

Has anyone had the same problem?

Thanks

Comment: hey there, i think there is no extension in the second code. this is the problem. so try give it an image with extension. it will work fine.

Comment: Hey Nitin, thanks for the comment, but as mentioned in the question adding the extension doesn't make it work on Android!

Comment: please try this one. for test. then let me know if it worked  or not.    https://c0.wallpaperflare.com/preview/249/371/595/human-person-move-forest.jpg

Comment: works on ios but not android

Comment: but i have checked it like now, the one i gave to you is working fine https://c0.wallpaperflare.com/preview/249/371/595/human-person-move-forest.jpg     bt the url given by you is not  https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/WXWOptDbw8QrmJ6HhsQVoRpDvqXIFbrgkOtI71d2lKkkDQhQMweVha4VD1rDEFsmphVKogC26oYn39FBXeyiLROJSHdUdP0JzF2Dx8wc125wh886iyU

Comment: Tried on a new app and it works fine... must have messed something in my app.. need to figure out what. I'll write an answer once discovered. Thanks for your help

Comment: my pleasure brother.